Kapton instead of air gap (ferrite core)
I'm working on a flyback converter topology and I want to create a 1 mm air gap in the ferrite core transformer in order to decrease AL. I didn't find one with air gape, I heard of a solution that is using a fine sandpaper to do it, but I'm afraid this way can damage the core. There is another solution which is using Kapton material. Since Kapton and air have the same permeability, I can put 1 mm thickness of Kapton, is it right?


I can put 1 mm thickness of Kapton, is it right ???


Kapton tape is a good solution
I've sanded down ferrites with no problem
You can try sanding an outer edge just to prove it to yourself
However, a distributed air gap using a spacer is usually better
I use cardboard sheets of 0.15 mm thickness bought from a hobby shop for prototyping


thanks a lot !!

does the cardboard have approximatly  the same permiability ??( 1mm air gap =1mm cardboard gap) because this is crucial in the calculations part

It's relative permeability is unity. A 1 mm overall spacing off usually means two gaps of effective distance 2 mm

You can use anything like that. Kapton is chemical and heat resistant so it's a reasonable choice. Note that you get double the effect of the (somewhat better) option of reducing the center post height since both paths are gapped.
I have a kit of colour-coded plastic shim materials that can be used to create prototype gaps quickly with no fuss. The minimum is 0.0005" (0.127mm) and maximum is 0.03" (0.762mm). Thin ones are polyester (mylar) and thick ones are PETG. The colour coding helps avoid errors- you can tell what gap you have in a prototype transformer design at a glance.
If you search for these, there are some stupidly high prices out there. Current proper price for 5 x 5" kit with 15 different sheets is less than $14 from a reputable US supplier.

1mm is rather thick to build up from polyimide (Kapton(R) is a brand) tape, but yes, that will do.  Mind that the adhesive layer is smooshy, so the thickness may not be as consistent as you'd like, or the core halves don't fit quite parallel but can be tilted by unbalanced forces.
I would suggest spacers of FR-4/G10, or polypropylene sheet/bar, etc. for larger gaps such as this.
All insulating nonmagnetic materials have μr = 1 so can be used here; preferably they should be part of the insulation system used in the construction.  If it's a one-off prototype, you might not care about the insulation system and exact materials, just as long as it works and up to nominal temperatures, without being fully safety certified.
Note that spacers air-gap the core all around, so that for typical cut-core geometries, the gap counts twice. If the calculated airgap is 1mm, you likely need more like 0.6 or 0.7mm spacing -- it will be more than half due to fringing.  Exactly how much more, is difficult to calculate; just trying a bunch of shims is the easiest route.  The fringing affects field intensity beyond the device outline and a spaced core has more EMI impact than a center-gapped (ground) core does.  Conversely, the somewhat distributed airgap will have lower eddy currents for the winding within, so that might be another consideration.
